# Build warning: There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Tags: windows, bash, reactjs, webpack

I got the following warning when I try to build the app1React in this [github-example](https://github.com/me-12/single-spa-portal-example), I didn't change any config.

By googling, this warning often caused by using wrong case in import statement, while this doesn't apply to me.

The difference here seems to be the backslash and forward-slash in the path that are being different.

C:\Users\yhe\Documents\GitHub...
vs
C:/Users/yhe/Documents/GitHub...

I am using window 10, does this has anything to do with the OS?
Anyone know how this can happen/fix?

> WARNING in (webpack)/buildin/global.js
>   There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
>   This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
>   Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
>   * C:\Users\yhe\Documents\GitHub\single-spa-portal-example\app1React\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
>       Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
>       C:\Users\yhe\Documents\GitHub\single-spa-portal-example\app1React\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
>   * C:\Users\yhe\Documents\Github\single-spa-portal-example\app1React\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
>       Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
>       C:\Users\yhe\Documents\Github\single-spa-portal-example\app1React\node_modules\symbol-observable\es\index.js @ (webpack)/buildin/global.js
>    @ C:/Users/yhe/Documents/GitHub/single-spa-portal-example/app1React/node_modules/punycode/punycode.js
>    @ C:/Users/yhe/Documents/GitHub/single-spa-portal-example/app1React/node_modules/url/url.js
>    @ (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9001
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9001 ./src/singleSpaEntry.js